# Drupal 7 set default value from database in hook_form

Tags: 7

I have implemented a hook menu:

```
$menu['question-view'] = array(
  'title' => 'Question View',
  'page callback' => 'item_view',
  'access arguments' => array('access question view'),
);
```

`item_view` callback is generated using table theme:

```
$output = theme('table', array(
  'header' => $header,
  'rows' => $rows,
));

$output .= theme('pager');
return $output;
```

which displays a table like this:

```
Question            Edit
Question1     Click here to edit
Question2     Click here to edit
Question3     Click here to edit
```

where "Question1", "Question2", and "Question3" are just questions like "What is your name?", which were all obtained from `questions` table in database.

When I click "Click here to edit", it should go to a form containing that question. For example, when I click edit beside Question2, the form should display Question2 as default value in the `$form['question']` field.

I want to do something like:

```
$form['question'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Question'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => ... // This should come from the question where I clicked.
);
```

Question:
How should I set the default value of `$form['question']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to add an indicator with edit question link i.e **query string** to load the selected question from database and pass the default value to the form.

> A **query string** is the part of a uniform resource locator (URL) that contains data to be passed to web applications.

"Click here to edit" link may look like (clean URL enabled):

http://www.your-domain.com/item_view/question/44

or

http://www.your-domain.com/question/44/edit

44 in both cases represent question id.

Then, take question id from the url and pass it to a mysql query to retrieve question title and assign it to `#default_value`

Example as follow:

```
function question_form() {

  $question_id = 0;

  // assuming url: www.your-domain.com/item_view/question/44
  if (arg(1) == 'question') {
    $question_id = arg(2);
  }

  // retrieve question title by question id
  $query = db_select('questions', 'q')
    ->fields('q', array('question_title'))
    ->condition('q.question_id', $question_id);
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();


  $form['question'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Question'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => ($result && isset($result['question_title']))? $result['question_title'] : '';
  );
}
```

Comment: `arg()` function. That's what I've been looking for! Thanks.

Comment: just for `arg()` :( anyways you're welcome :)